# React Native: Does it make sense to use firebase and sqlite at the same time?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I want to make an application that works in offline and online mode. Is it logical to use sqlite and firebase at the same time for this? Or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase has an offline storage mode (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline)

That doesn't necessarily mean that you don't need to come up with specific solutions for your app architecture, but it'll *probably* prevent you from having to use both sqlite and Firebase.